# Strong name is must

Tags: .net, gac

Is it necessary to provide strong name to an assembly before putting it in GAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look [here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/28/strongnaming.html) for a very good explanation about strong naming and signing. 
In the article it says you can delay the signing of an assembly and still register the assembly into the GAC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

See the [MSDN docs on it:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315682)

> In order to install an assembly in the
>   GAC, **you must give** the assembly a
>   **strong** (that is, globally unique)
>   **name**. Actually, it is not a name but a
>   cryptographic hash key, or signature.
>   The strong name ensures correct
>   component versioning, which helps to
>   prevent components that have the same
>   name from conflicting with each other
>   or being incorrectly used by a
>   consuming application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Part of the reason for doing this is so that you can guarantee that nobody has installed a malicious piece of code that is mimicking a legitimate DLL. Imagine the havoc it somebody replaced System.Data with a piece of malware.

Comment: The 'malicious code' problem is an extreme corner case. The purpose of Signing is much broader.

Comment: I agree - which is why I stated it was part of the reason (it's actually a very important reason).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is required to give the assembly a strong name in order [to install it in the GAC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315682).